# Global game variables not being updated

Tags: python, global

I am making a game with two main global variables

```
game_over = False
flying = True
```

In my Bird class i can reference these variables. Nowhere in the Bird() class do i change these variables

```
class Bird(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
    def update(self):
        if (flying == True) and (game_over == False):
            ...
        if game_over == False:
            ...
```

However, in another class i need to both reference and set these variables

```
class Button1(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
    def update(self):
        if game_over == True:
           ...
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1 and self.clicked == False:
                ...
                game_over = False
                flying = True
```

Here, I get the error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'game_over' referenced before assignment
```

Instead of setting the global game_over and global flying, it creates new local variables game_over and flying.
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to set global variables in Python, you need to declare them at the top of the function. For example,

```py
def update(self):
    global flying, game_over
    if game_over == True:
       ...
        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1 and self.clicked == False:
            ...
            game_over = False
            flying = True
        ...
```

Comment: The global variables have already been defined. I tried doing that, but it says SyntaxError: name 'game_over' is used prior to global declaration

Comment: @VasuK Are the globals defined in the same python file as the `update()` function?

Comment: yes and its working in all other classes only in the Button1 class its not working